# Discord.js - How to servermute a mentioned member?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

*Hey,
I've written a working version of my code a while ago, but I've lost it and can't get it working again.*

I try to servermute a mentioned member, but my code won't work.

```
if(command == "mute") {
    const person = message.mentions.members.first();
    person.voice.setMute(true);
}
```

I've also tried these ones and none of them work:

```
//version1
const user = message.mentions.users.first();
const person = message.guild.members(user);

//version2
const person = message.guild.members(message.mentions.users.first());
```

My bot works fine except these parts above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try using this code:

```
let person = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first());
```

I personally use this for my bots and it works headache-free. Let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: I find the problem it was my command handler not my function (._. )

Answer (score 0):

Try using a add role and remove role function. For example:

```
let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'members');
let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'muted');

if (!args[1]) {
   memberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id);
   memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
   message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been muted`);
   return
}
memberTarget.roles.remove(mainRole.id);
memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been muted for ${ms(ms(args[1]))}`);
 
            setTimeout(function () {
                memberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole.id);
                memberTarget.roles.add(mainRole.id);
            }, ms(args[1]));
        } else {
            message.channel.send(`Can't find that member/did not specify a member!`);
        }
```

This code removes the role called "members" from the user mentioned and gives the user mentioned the role "muted".
For the roles, you have to make sure the user mentioned to mute must have the main role "members".
If the user is not real or not a valid user, the code will send the message: "Can't find that member/did not specify a member!".

Comment: I know this method, but I try to avoid it because it's unsmooth and I already got the servermute bot running in the past and just lose it like I said
But thx anyways